# Asignar valores a un enum

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java y estoy empezando con los enum. Tengo el siguiente enum definido:

```
public enum Position {
 
    GOALKEEPER ("BLACK"),
    DEFENDER ("RED"),
    MIDFIELDER ("GREEN"),
    FORWARD ("BLUE");
    // Variable local
    private String color;
```

Cada uno de estos valores corresponde a una posición de futbolista y cada una de estas posiciones tiene un color asignado. La asignación es la siguiente:

- GOALKEEPER --> BLACK
- DEFENDER --> RED
- MIDFIELDER --> GREEN
- FORWARD --> BLUE

Necesito crear un método llamado

```
getColors()
```

que devuelva un array de String con los calores de cada uno de los valores del enum. He creado el siguiente test para verificar la implementación del método:

```
assertEquals(Arrays.toString(new String[]{"BLACK, RED, GREEN, BLUE"}), Arrays.toString(Position.getColors()));
```

De momento, he hecho lo siguiente:

```
public enum Position {

    GOALKEEPER("BLACK"),
    DEFENDER("RED"),
    MIDFIELDER("GREEN"),
    FORWARD("BLUE");
    // Variable local
    private String color;

    // Constructor que guarda el paràmetre color
    private Position(String color){
        this.color=color;
    }

    // Obtenemos el color
    public String getColor() {return color;}

      public String [] getColors() {
        return Position.values();
    }
```

No consigo que funcione.. el `.values()` me da la lista de colores pero despues no se como asignarlos con el constructor privado `Position`.

Comment: Le añades un atributo de tipo String al Enum, `color`, y para cada elemento del Enum, se lo asignas.

Comment: el atributo color ya lo añadi, pero tengo el problema en como devolver el vector String[]  y asignar el color según la posición

Comment: Pues es que, en la definición del Enum, no lo estás asignando efectivamente. Has probado alguna forma de hacerlo??

Comment: A través del método getColors() quiero recuperar las constantes del enum con un Position.values(), el problema es que después quiero hacer un lookup con otro vector que almacenen los colores String [] colors = new String[] {"BLACK","RED","GREEN","BLUE"}. A partir de aquí hacer la asignación pero no se como. Quizás haya alguna forma más fácil...

Comment: Revisa cómo funciona un Enum, porque no tienes claro cómo se asignan estos atributos. No hay tal cosa como la posibilidad de asignarle valores a los atributos después de definirlo. El color se asigna en la declaración.

Comment: Creo que empiezo a entenderte... asigné el color en la declaración como me dijiste. Ahora me falta crear el método...

Comment: Revisa la documentación del Enum y prueba.

Comment: Sigo intentándolo pero no acabo de ver la luz...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131402/discussion-between-alfabravo-and-panri93).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El camino es tratar mejor al Enum, que es una clase especial y hay que tratarla como tal. :)

Ya tienes el atributo con el color. Falta que obtengas los colores

```
public static String[] getColors() {
    return Arrays.stream(PositionEnum.values()).map(PositionEnum::getColor).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Se ve feo pero es simple. Le dices al stream que a) agarre el .values, b) por cada elemento, haga getColor, c) por cada salida, la mande a un array.

Y ya después, si uno hace algo en otra clase como

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] pepito = PositionEnum.getColors();
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pepito));
}
```

Va a pintar un array de colores :)